# proving the divergence or convergence of an improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$\int_0^1$${\frac {e^{x^2}}{{\sqrt[3]{x}} - \tan x}}$$dx$
I have to determine whether the above integral diverges or converges. Well, over the interval (0, 1) the denominator has another root apart from $0$ , say $\alpha$. First of all since $e^{x^2}$ is always positive an never zero by the $\lim$ $\frac fg$ formula I proved that the divergence or convergence of the above integral is equivalent to $\int_0^1$${\frac {1}{{\sqrt[3]{x}} - \tan x}}$$dx$  . other than that i don't know how to find an easier function for the denominator nothing comes to mind. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The first ptoblem would be around $x=0$.

Use taylor expansion of the integrand
$$\frac {e^{x^2}}{{\sqrt[3]{x} - \tan (x)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}+\sqrt[3]{x}+x+2 x^{5/3}+O\left(x^{7/3}\right)$$ So, no problem (integrate termwise)

Now, the problem is at $x=\frac \pi 4 < 1$

Comment: but pi/4 is not the root of the denominator how can we find the root?